# Geospatial pdfs and Avenza

Tags: export, geospatial-pdf, avenza

I have created a Mapbook with each page containing a section of the main map and an index map.  They both seem to be georeferenced when exported in a PDF.

When a user with an Apple product uses the map with Avenza PDF, the current position, tracks, and place marks are directed to the index map, not the main map.

Is there a way to georeference ONE and NOT both of the maps?

Comment: Is the map multi-page, or just an index map in box in the corner of the page?

Comment: If you can't run a second export without the index map in it (DDP makes that easy but you may have other reasons not to do so), you might see if the order of the data frames in your map TOC makes a difference on your next pdf export.  For instance if the Index data frame is on top of the main one, reverse that order.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, PDF Maps does try to use the larger of the two referenced data frames on your map for all location functionality. However, we have seen instances where this does not always work correctly, and we are looking into ways to improve this. In the meantime, you will have to remove the georeferencing from one of the data frames so that the location tools are directed to the correct map.

Comment: FYI we have a tag for [tag:mapublisher] and I've just created one for [tag:avenza] that you can use to isolate/track/follow posts related to your software. It's possible that might get turned into 'avenza-pdf-maps' - we'll see.